# Does LongListSelector make Lazy Load for us?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, windows-phone-8

I'm on windows phone 8 project, in this project, I use panorama template. In first panorama I show the news in a longlistselector.

First, I was showing 15 news and nothing was a problem for performance. But now I show 50 news and started to make load time longer I think.

My question is, longlistselector make lazy loading for us or should we make something for it like windows stores one. Or I mean, When I scroll bottoms, It gets the small pictures and titles ?

I've reached ItemRealized and UnRealized events. Should I focus on them ?

By the way, I don't use MVVM correctly. I get the data from web api and binds it to controls.

Comment: What do you mean by lazy load? Poor performance or defering intialization of objects [aka lazy loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading)? Second, you might show some code so we can better help you.

Comment: Do you know some mobile application does that; when you scroll down, new pictures, titles appears, you scroll more, new contents comes again and again.. I mean this.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve lazy-loading using the OnItemRealized event, take a look here http://www.damirscorner.com/InfiniteScrollingWithIncrementalLoadingInWindowsPhone8.aspx

```
private void OnItemRealized(object sender, ItemRealizationEventArgs e)
{
    var longListSelector = sender as LongListSelector;
    if (longListSelector == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    var item = e.Container.Content;
    var items = longListSelector.ItemsSource;
    var index = items.IndexOf(item);

    if (items.Count - index <= 1)
    {
        //ask for more items and add theme here
    }
}
```

Comment: Does not matter, do not copy the whole code just get inspired

Comment: I do not copy whole code. I googled and found that page before asking here. If you want to speak like this, you do not have to try putting some text and links here, do not try to show them as answer.

Comment: the code from the links shows you to use the OnItemRealized and when to ask for more items to add to the LongListSelector

Comment: ItemRealized method(like in windows phone store) loads 10 images and waits, loads 10 images and wait. I need help about loading when scrolling trough bottom.. Thanks anyway.